# In 'choose which badge to track' things spill over the bottom of the pop up window

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, badges

On TeX.SX, if you look at your profile and click on the 'choose which badge to track' button, the badges spill over the bottom side of the pop up window:

[image]

This does not happen on Stack Overflow:

[image]

Therefore, I assume this is a bug.

I can reproduce this bug on:

1. Mac OS X 10.11.3 & Firefox 44.0.2
2. Mac OS X 10.11.3 & Google Chrome 48.0.2564.116
3. Mac OS X 10.11.3 & Safari 9.0.3

Comment: I can't confirm this for FF 42 on Linux, neither for regular badges nor for tag badges

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I can reproduce it on a Mac on Safari, Firefox, and Google Chrome.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Iceweasel 31.8.0 (yeah I know it's a pretty old version)

Comment: I can reproduce this with FF 40 on Linux, however

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. The problem arose because font the filter tabs use have a wider letter-spacing. Combine that with having the selected filter in bold, and that pushed the input field down.

This has been corrected. It should look like this now:

[image: Badge popup screenshot]